# How to not repeat items in $SESSION list?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session

I'm creating a shopping cart. Only with session variables. I want something simple, no database, it is only for initial system (later that perhaps use database and logins)

I click in a product and use URL to add in SESSION variable

Exemple Product: Orange

Sent url

```
site.com/?page=buy&add=Orange&type=fruit
```

Then...

```
session_start();

//Create 'cart' if it doesn't already exist
if (!isset($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'])){ $_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'] = array(); }

if (isset($_GET['add'])){
//Adding an Item
//Store it in a Array
$ITEM = array(
    //Item name     
    'name' => $_GET['add'],
    'type' => $_GET['tipo'],

//Item Price

);
```

For print, I use:

```
  $itemType = ""; 
   foreach ($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'] as $itemNumber => $item) {
     if($itemType == $item['type']) {
       // skip...don't print again
     } else { 
        echo $item['type']; 
     }
     echo $item['name']; 
     $itemType = $item['type'];
    }
```

But My problem is, when I print I see something like this:

```
Fruit:
  Orange
  Orange
  Apple 
Food
 Meat
```

Someone can tell me how do I only appear once one "Fruit". How do I comparison is already is repeated?
Only 1 orange.

```
Fruit:
      Orange
      Apple 
    Food
     Meat
```

Comment: When you add stuff, check if was not already added. But in a cart you may want to add multiple items of the same kind, so consider saving the count as well.

Comment: That shouldn't happen with the code you've shown; could you do `var_dump($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART']);`?

Comment: you should be keying the cart with the ID of the product in question, e.g. `$_SESSION['cart'][$productID] = array('details of product here');`. Then it's a simple matter of keeping everything in one place.

Answer (score 0):

use `array_unique()` function of PHP. Manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Or you can use memoization technique to check if this item has been seen earlier in this loop.

```
$itemType = ""; 
foreach ($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'] as $itemNumber => $item) {
 if($itemType == $item['type']) {
   // skip...don't print again
 } else { 
    echo $item['type']; 
 }
 if(!isset($memo[$item['name']]))  
 echo $item['name']; 
 $memo[$item['name']] = 1;
 $itemType = $item['type'];
}
```

Comment: I try to create like this, but is not working $result= array( //Item name 'name' => $_GET['add'], 'type' => $_GET['tipo'], //Item Price ); $ITEM= array_unique($result);

Comment: @user2428731 Try like: `$ITEM = $_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART']; $ITEM = array_unique($ITEM);` then iterate over `$ITEM` as you're doing right now, I mean `foreach ($ITEM as $itemNumber => $item) {`

Comment: Hi, it's only print 1 item. Nothing more

Comment: dear downvoter could you help me with a reason for -1? Thanks

Comment: Hi! Thanks, I use that $memo, but I have a problem on remove.

Answer (score -1):

just use array_unique

```
foreach (array_unique($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART']) as $itemNumber => $item) {
     if($itemType == $item['type']) {
       // skip...don't print again
     } else { 
        echo $item['type']; 
     }
     echo $item['name']; 
     $itemType = $item['type'];
    }
```

Comment: @ can you post pint_r($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART']) ?

Comment: It's only print 1 item. Because, when I use array_unique. If I have fruit: orange, fruit:banana. Only print first FRUIT.

Comment: @user2428731 it wont help with this data ,i need whole data,seems it has array with in array.